# Assign leader to partitions of kafka topic while creating topics in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I have single kafka broker and am implementing kafka in nodeJS using kafka-node. I want to create a single topic with 3 partitions. While doing this, problem occuring is only first partition is getting leader assign where as other two partitions are not getting leaders. I want to assign leaders to all of the partitions. Can anyone please tell me how could I do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
var client = new kafka.KafkaClient();
    var topic = 't-26';
    var topicsToCreate = [
        {
            topic: topic,
            partitions: 3,
            Leader: 0,
            replicationFactor: 1,
            replicaAssignment: [
            {
              partition: 0,
              replicas: [0]
            },
            {
                partition: 1,
                replicas: [1]
            },
            {
                partition: 2,
                replicas: [2]
            }
          ]
        },
        ];
        client.createTopics(topicsToCreate, (error, result) => {
             console.log(result);
        });
```

Topic created as follows -

```
Topic: t-26     PartitionCount: 3       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: t-26     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: t-26     Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 1     Isr:
        Topic: t-26     Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 2     Isr:
```

Comment: Hi @PNJain, did below answer helped you solve your question? If so, would appreciate it if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of @mike I got a hint and resolved the issue. I did the following -

remove `leader=0` and set all replicas to 0 `replicas: [0]`

Answer (score 2):

You are "globally" defining the Leader to be on broker with id `0` whereas you want to have the partitions `1` and `2` located on other brokers. As you defined the replication to be one, this is contradicting itself. Remove the part about the `Leader` and it should automatically create the partitions leaders on the brokers you want.

Comment: actually there are no errors. But thanks to you because I got a hint and set all replicas to 0 and now issue is resolved